# Linux: cat matching files in date order?

Tags: linux, command-line

I have a few files in a directory with names similar to

- `_system1.log`
- `_system2.log`
- `_system3.log`
- `other.log`

but they are not created in that order.

**Is there a simple, non-hardcoded, way to `cat` the files starting with the underscore in date order?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Quick 'n' dirty:

```
cat `ls -t _system*.log`
```

Safer:

```
ls -1t _system*.log | xargs -d'\n' cat
```

Comment: just make sure that ls is not aliased to 'ls -F' or similar, 
in your shell profile. If it does, you may get unwanted *-expansions in your output. To be safe, use /bin/ls -t

Comment: Or `\ls` if you don't want to specify the location of ls.

Comment: Since these are log files, you probably want to use `ls -1tr` (to order the earliest file first).

Answer (score 1):

Use `ls`:

```
ls -1t | xargs cat
```

Comment: Sorry, I added a bit to my question, but have worked out the changes I need.

My final answer is:

`ls -1rt _* | xargs -d'\n' cat`

Answer (score 0):

`ls -1 | xargs cat`

Comment: Date order. You need to add the "-t" option.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate and also store them in a single file according to their time of creation and also you can specify the files which you want to concatenate. Here, I find it very useful. The following command will concatenate the files which are arranged according to their time of creaction and have common string 'xyz' in their file name and store all of them in outputfile.

cat $(ls -t  |grep    xyz)>outputfile